# LinkedIn Javascript API - login button not appearing for some users

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am using the `LinkedIn Javascript API` for an `MVC4` web application that allows users to login via `LinkedIn`. I am experiencing some strange issues where the LinkedIn button does not appear at all for some users, without any errors in the `Javascript` console.

In my Shared/Layout view, I make reference to the `LinkedIn Javascript API` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url"> 
  api_key: key
  authorize: true
  scope: r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network
</script>
```

And in my login page I use the standard LinkedIn login button script:

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onauth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
```

Where `onLinkedInAuth` simply redirects the user to the relevant page on successful login.

I have never had a problem running on my own machine. And many other users of my website have used the Sign In button with no problems at all.

But other users have found that the `LinkedIn` sign in button does not appear at all when they visit the login page. Although they have found that if they log in to `LinkedIn` before visiting the login page, then the login page will automatically call the onauth method and log the user into my application. I have only witnessed this problem with `Chrome`, but will have to double check to see if you users are experiencing the problem in any other browsers.

I'm not sure what else I can provide here really. Has anyone else experienced the same thing/got any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url"> 
  api_key: key
  authorize: false
  scope: r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network
</script>
```

in place of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url"> 
  api_key: key
  authorize: true
  scope: r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network
</script>
```

you can set authorize: false than your problem is solved.

thanks
Simranjeet singh

Comment: you mean just change the authorize value? I don't want to that because I want my app to auto-login the user if they are already signed in to LinkedIN.